# How to use nokogiri to get text between two elements in different parents

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to get Nokogiri to help me find text between two tags. 
In this case, i want the text between **< strong >** and **< ul >** that might be in different parent-nodes.

The HTML is dynamic and could vary a lot.

Here are three cases

Case 1: The expected output would be "**I'm not strong**"

```
<p>
  I'm not interesting
</p>
<p>
  <strong>I'm strong</strong>
  <span>I'm not strong</span>
</p>
<ul>
  <li> I'm a list item </li>
  <li> Me too </li>
</ul>
```

Case 2: The expected output would be **nil** or **empty-string**

```
<p>
  I'm not interesting
</p>
<div>
  <strong>I'm strong</strong></br>
</div>
<ul>
  <li> I'm a list item </li>
  <li> Me too </li>
</ul>
```

Case 3: The expected output would be **I'm not strong**

```
<p>
  I'm not interesting
</p>
<strong>I'm strong</strong>
<p>I'm not strong</strong>
<ul>
  <li> I'm a list item </li>
  <li> Me to </li>
</ul>
```

Thank you

Comment: Please provide some valid HTML.. you have given <p> inside <p> which is invaild it seems.. as per the my test [here](http://goo.gl/9G4HXO)

Comment: your case 3 is still invalid

Answer (score 1):

Here is the *specs* as per the samples given by you :

Inside the *test.rb* file :

```
require 'nokogiri'

def get_text_of_a_node(doc, xpath)
  doc.at_xpath(xpath).to_s
end
```

Then inside the *test_spec.rb* file :

```
require_relative '../test.rb'
require 'rspec'

describe "#get_text_of_a_node" do
  let(:xpath) { ".//strong[text()=\"I'm strong\"]/following-sibling::span/text()" }

  context "when <span> tag is present after <strong> with text" do
    let(:xml) do
        "<p>
          I'm not interesting
        </p>
        <p>
            <strong>I'm strong</strong>
            <span>I'm not strong</span>
        </p>
        <ul>
            <li> I'm a list item </li>
            <li> Me too </li>
        </ul>"
    end
    let(:doc) { Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse xml.strip }

    it "returns text" do
      expect(get_text_of_a_node(doc, xpath)).to eq("I'm not strong")
    end
  end 

  context "when <span> tag is absent after <strong>" do
    let(:xml) do
        "<p>
          I'm not interesting
        </p>
        <div>
            <strong>I'm strong</strong>
        </br>undefined</div>undefined<ul>
        <li> I'm a list item </li>
        <li> Me too </li>undefined</ul>"
    end
    let(:doc) { Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse xml.strip }

    it "returns empty string" do
      expect(get_text_of_a_node(doc, xpath)).to be_empty
    end
  end
end
```

All tests are passed :

```
[shreyas@arup_ruby (master)]$ rspec spec/test_spec.rb
..

Finished in 0.04067 seconds (files took 0.12591 seconds to load)
2 examples, 0 failures

[shreyas@arup_ruby (master)]$
```

Comment: This works for these specific cases, not dynamically. But its very nice built. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using Nokogiri xpath with the selector

```
//strong/following::*[not(self::ul|self::li)]
```

Does the trick. To get the text between the tags you can use

```
n.xpath("*//strong/following::*[not(self::ul|self::li)]").text
> "I'm not strong"
```

Comment: This will also return any nodes _after_ the list, which I don’t think you want.

Comment: @matt yes, i realized this. I haven't found a good solution for "stop" on first Ul...